# Julia lang remove duplicates in a list of tuples considering the second element

Tags: tuples, julia

Is there an easy way to remove duplicates of a list of tuples where for the duplicates only the second element is considered? For example when I have the following list:

```
a = [("a",1),("b",3),("c",4),("d",8),("e",1)]
```

I want to end up with:

```
a = [("b",3),("c",4),("d",8),("e",1)]
```

I doesn't matter if I keep "a" or "e".

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the [`unique(f, itr)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/#Base.unique) method to do this; it returns the elements of `itr` where `f` returns unique values.

```
julia> unique(x->x[2], a)
4-element Array{Tuple{String,Int64},1}:
 ("a", 1)
 ("b", 3)
 ("c", 4)
 ("d", 8)
```